# FIDE 2022 Presidential Elections - Runners and Riders?

Tags: fide

There is a 4 year FIDE election cycle and with [Dvorkovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkady_Dvorkovich) elected in 2018 everybody knew there would be an election this year. With both the 2022 Olympiad and FIDE Congress due to be held in Russia this was originally thought to be a shoe-in for a 2nd term for Dvorkovich, not least because he appears to be the most competent and least corrupt president that FIDE has had for several decades.

However Russia's war against Ukraine meant that the Olympiad and Congress have both moved to Chennai in India and Dvorkovich, as a former deputy prime minister of Russia, is viewed by many as too close to Putin's regime to be allowed to continue his role in FIDE and this has opened up the position for serious opposition candidates to run.

Who are the people running against Dvorkovich for the post of FIDE President?

Answer (score 4):

**Arkady Dvorkovich**

Perhaps worth starting with Dvorkovich's announcement [here](https://fide.com/news/1756) on Friday 13th May two days after FIDE made their [official call for candidates](https://fide.com/news/1740). [Dvorkovich](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/34404449) is certainly not taking this lightly. His heavyweight team includes former World Champion, [Vishy Anand](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/5000017), as his Deputy President and [GM Zhu Chen](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/8600546) as Treasurer.

However, first out of the blocks on 30th April, almost two weeks before FIDE's call for candidates was:

**[Enyonam Sewa Fumey](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/21200033)**

More of a politician than a chess player (despite being a Candidate Master his all-time highest rating is 1870), he became President of the Togo Chess Federation in 2017 and shortly after was part of Dvorkovich's successful campaign becoming FIDE General Secretary. So he is actually running against his boss. His candidacy is reported on the FIDE website [here](https://fide.com/news/1722).

Update: According to this [ChesscomLive tweet](https://twitter.com/ChesscomLive/status/1534493511411802113):

> Enyonam Sewa Fumey from Togo won't be among the FIDE presidential candidates as he could not get the necessary support from at least one federation in Europe.

**[Inal Sheripov](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/24123609)**

With a 2290 rapid rating (no standard or blitz) from a one-off tournament (the 2018 Belgium rapid championships) he is more of a film maker and politician than chess player. Although he was a strong Chechen player in his youth. There are more details about him and his candidacy [here](https://www.chess-international.com/?p=56780). Not very encouraging is this:

> The first vice-president on Sheripov's team is Lewis Ncube (Zambia), a well-known FIDE official best known from the Ilyumzhinov era
> ...
> Ncube was the only one who voted against Ilyumzhinov's resignation at the FIDE Council meeting in spring 2018

**[Andrei Barishpolets](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/14117207)**

A young (31) Ukrainian GM with no political experience, he looks very much like an outsider. FIDE is not [Eurovision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurovision_Song_Contest_2022). His manifesto is [here](https://www.chess-international.com/?p=56783). Summary - "definitely not related to Dvorkovich, nor Ilyumzhinov, nor the Kremlin".

Update: With the inclusion of Peter Heine Nielson, one of Magnus Carlsen's seconds, in his team he becomes less of an outsider. [Getting the backing](https://twitter.com/MagnusCarlsen/status/1534138530548658179) of the World Champion also counts for something:

> Chess federations of the Americas! Can one of you please pledge your support to the Baryshpolets/Nielsen ticket so @PHChess can focus on prep instead?